# We can’t log you in because of the following error. Remote_Error: The remote service returned an error

Tags: managed-package, namedcredentials, auth-provider, auth, authproviderpluginclass

I have a strange case. I have custom Auth Provider, trying to authorize named credential and getting:

Problem Logging In
We can’t log you in because of the following error. For more information, contact your Salesforce administrator.

Remote_Error: The remote service returned an error

What more - I was testing those components installed in managed package. When I'm deploying the same code using SFDX of course it works perfectly. Only when its installed by managed package i got this error.

What can cause that? I've checked logs, remote site settings, urls, permissions and looks fine. Could that be a namespace issues or something different?
Can you help?

Comment: Does it work when you try with Test-Only Initialization URL?